# How to expose functions globally through webpack in a web app?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to expose some functions which I have in my `helpers.js` file globally, so that I can directly call them without having to import them. Here is my javascript file:

```
function icon_string(num, white){
    return "https://flyhomes.imgix.net/icons/icons_" + (white ? "w" : "b") +"_v2-" + num.toString() + ".svg";
}

Number.prototype.format = function(decPlaces, thouSeparator, decSeparator) {
    var n = this,
        decPlaces = isNaN(decPlaces = Math.abs(decPlaces)) ? 2 : decPlaces,
        decSeparator = decSeparator == undefined ? "." : decSeparator,
        thouSeparator = thouSeparator == undefined ? "," : thouSeparator,
        sign = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(decPlaces)) + "",
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return sign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thouSeparator : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thouSeparator) + (decPlaces ? decSeparator + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(decPlaces).slice(2) : "");
};

Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
  if (new_index >= this.length) {
      var k = new_index - this.length;
      while ((k--) + 1) {
          this.push(undefined);
      }
  }
  this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return this; // for testing purposes
};

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}


String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};


function containsObjectID(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].id === obj.id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function containsObjectIndex(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].id === obj.id) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}

function removeQueryStringParameter(url, parameter) {
    var urlparts= url.split('?');   
    if (urlparts.length>=2) {

        var prefix= encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
        var pars= urlparts[1].split(/[&;]/g);

        for (var i= pars.length; i-- > 0;) {    
            if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== -1) {  
                pars.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        url= urlparts[0]+'?'+pars.join('&');
        return url;
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}

function paramsToObject(params){
    var query_string = {};
    var query = params;
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
          // If first entry with this name
      if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
        query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
          // If second entry with this name
      } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
        var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
        query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
          // If third or later entry with this name
      } else {
        query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
      }
    } 
      return query_string;
}

function humanize(str) {
  var frags = str.split('_');
  frags[0] = frags[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + frags[0].slice(1);
  return frags.join(' ');
}

String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

// Warn if overriding existing method
if(Array.prototype.equals)
  console.warn("Overriding existing Array.prototype.equals. Possible causes: New API defines the method, there's a framework conflict or you've got double inclusions in your code.");
// attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
  // if the other array is a falsy value, return
  if (!array)
      return false;

  // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
  if (this.length != array.length)
      return false;

  for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
      // Check if we have nested arrays
      if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
          // recurse into the nested arrays
          if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
              return false;       
      }           
      else if (this[i] != array[i]) { 
          // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
          return false;   
      }           
  }       
  return true;
}
// Hide method from for-in loops
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "equals", {enumerable: false});

exports.onMobile = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
```

Sorry for adding the whole file, but I would like to draw attention to some of the functions which are applied to base classes themselves (such as Number, String etc), while others are declared as is.

To expose them, I tried adding alias in `webpack.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.json', '.jsx', '.js'],
    alias: {
      'helpers': path.resolve(__dirname, './vendor/assets/javascripts/helpers.js')
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      helpers: 'helpers'
    })
  ],
  ...
};
```

But as I was skeptical, it didn't work. I copied this idea from the instance when we need a specific library globally and we have it's javascript file, we follow the above approach. But obviously, that's related to importing a specific file and not a file containing such functions and exporting them globally at once. Can you help me how to do it through `webpack` or where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That alias just holds the value of the location of your helpers.js file.
Referencing it within other files just means the alias is replaced with the helpers file *String* and *not* its contents.

I'd also think quite carefully about *not* polluting the global scope with your helper functions.  If anything you can just use a namespace variable that will hold your functions as methods of the name space.  Think lodash's '`_`'  or even more simply vanilla JS's `Math` object.

**[BTW: Augmenting or extending the native JavaScript object is highly
 discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/2902660).**

Comment: I get your point but right now I am in the middle of a refactor of application in which I cannot change the current implementation where all these functions were globally declared(using rails application). But now I want them to be declared through webpack. Is it possible? Or do you suggest that I should just refactor the usages of these functions with a library such as `lodash`?

Comment: You could create a module with these functions exported as methods within the exported object.  You can then import/require this file in other modules of your project and use them accordingly